# Identify rows which are identical in 2 different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have 2 tables with same schema (one is a temptable)

Both temp table and main table will have few rows which are identical.

I need to UPDATE the main table for which, the same entry exists on the temptable.

What is the best possible way to do it.

The tables have more than 100 columns. So is it possible do it without listing out all the columns in the query?

Comment: Can you show us some code? What have you tried?

Comment: When are two rows equal, in your case? All columns are the same or just the unique key is the same?

Comment: Thanks Hans.Two rows are equal when all values in all columns matches. There is no unique key

Comment: What are you updating if all columns have to have the same value to qualify as match?

Comment: @Nikola.. Thanks.. Well I have maintable with say 1000 records. I will be fetching some records say 10 from main table to temptable.   Later on for some the records which are fetched , i need to update a flag in the main table for the record. For this purpose, I need to identify those records in the main table which are in the temptable.

Comment: When you say "it is not possible to list out all the columns in the query", I suspect what you mean is it is not desirable to list all the columns. Unfortunately without using Dynamic SQL, or introducing a surrogate primary key you will have to define how you want to identify 'Matching' rows. To save time in writing any `JOIN` Or `MERGE` statements something like the following will help: `SELECT ' AND MainTable.' + COLUMN_NAME + ' = TempTable.' + COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YourTable'`

Comment: You will be better off if you introduce identity column as a primary key to your main table. If you cannot, IMHO there is no way of escaping the horror of a hundred column join.

Comment: @Nikola. I will not be able to introduce any identity column as this is a table is in production database

Comment: @GarethD : rephrasing the question as I did not meant it that way . I was looking a better solution without listing all the columns

Comment: This approach will not work. Could you open new question trying to explain what you need to do? Perhaps there is a way to update the records without using temporary table. Sql Server 2008 has many tools at your disposal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for [Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx). The query:

```
select *
from TableA
intersect
select * 
from TableB
```

retrieves rows found in both sets.

As for a hundred columns question, open SQL Server Management Studio, find your table in tables, right click and select "Script table as", then "Insert to", then "New query window" to get comma separated list of columns.

Comment: He probably wants EXCEPT then to return rows that are different... still the fun of doing the update with no primary key though!

Comment: @DaleBurrell OP did say `the same entry exists on the temptable`, so I presume that OP wants to mark original records rather than copy values from temporary table. This will be the most bloated join ever, though ;-)

Comment: So he did :) its only a few minutes work to code the scheme query cursor to dynamically build the query - would be quite fun.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the MERGE statement. A good guide for this is at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522.aspx

Now, as far as listing out the columns goes, just use the unique key to figure out whether the rows are common or not.

Comment: thanks Amit. The table  is designed in such a way that there isnt any unique key.  All the values in all columns have to be matched..

Comment: Then, your unique key is to match all columns. Or, even better (performance-wise), you can use the row checksums to do the comparison (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189788.aspx)

Comment: @vstrien - Using CHECKSUM is a pretty dangerous join predicate.  It's not like a GUID where it's essentially impossible to ever get a collision, with CHECKSUM you *will* eventually get a collision.

Comment: @Dems: True. I misread the question and thought it was about appending missing rows (in which case it's worth a try to see if you can get everything eventually complete with a CHECKSUM)

Answer (score 2):

You could build the query dynamically. I don't think it is a particularly elegant solution but it would do the job:

```
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(100),
        @FlagColumn VARCHAR(100)

SET @TableName = 'TestTable'
SET @FlagColumn = 'FlagColumn'
-- BUILD THE TEMPORARY TABLE
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = 'SELECT * INTO ##' + @TableName + ' FROM ' + @TableName
EXEC(@SQL)

-- DO STUFF

-- BUILD SQL FOR MERGE STATEMENT
SET @SQL = ''
SELECT  @SQL = @SQL + ' AND main.' + COLUMN_NAME + ' = temp.' + COLUMN_NAME
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE   TABLE_NAME = @TableName
AND     COLUMN_NAME != @FlagColumn

SET @SQL = 'MERGE INTO ' + @TableName + ' main USING ##' + @TableName + ' temp ON ' + STUFF(@SQL, 1, 5, '') + 
            ' WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET ' + @FlagColumn + ' = 1;'
-- EXECUTE MERGE STATEMENT
EXEC (@SQL)

-- DROP TEMP TABLE
SET @SQL = 'DROP TABLE ##' + @TableName
EXEC (@SQL)
```

This is more dynamic than necessary, and could be simplified as none of the temporary table stuff needs to be done dynamically, I have just done this because I don't know your table names, or your temp table name.

I've tested this by creating the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable (FlagColumn BIT)
DECLARE @i INT = 1
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
WHILE @i < 100
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE TestTable ADD COLUMN' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @i) + ' INT'
        EXEC (@SQL)
        SET @i = @i + 1
    END
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update MyTable set
  ColumnX = ?? /* Update the columns your require to the new values */
  , ColumnY = ??
from MyTable
inner join MyTempTable T on T.ColumnA = MyTable.ColumnA
  and MyTable.ColumnB = T.ColumnB
/* Add as many conditions as necessary to be a match */
```

if the column can be null you have to handle that as either:

```
where ((MyTable.ColumnA is null and T.ColumnA is null) or MyTable.ColumnA = T.ColumnA)
```

or if you know that a particular value is invalid as 0 is in an identify column you can do

```
where coalesce(MyTable.ColumnA,0) = coalesce(T.ColumnA,0)
```

Comment: Thanks.But I have more than 100 columns int the table.So it is not possible to list out all the columns in the query. So is there any better solution

Comment: If you want some fun, write a query to obtain the columns of your table from the schema. Then using a cursor/temp table loop through them and construct a string containing the SQL you need to do the update - will maybe be faster than building it by hand. Or script the table and then use text search and replace to build the query.

Comment: You can list 100 columns? It will just be very boring :)